# Simple C++ Unit Conversion

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a beginner-level program that converts input from one unit of time to another. Essentially what I'm after is this: the user inputs a number of days, hours, and minutes, and those values get converted to both weeks and seconds. Here is what I have so far, which displays "0" for both weeks and seconds no matter the input.

EDIT: Fixed multiplication, new code for weeks. Still a garbage value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int days, hours, minutes, weeks, seconds;

    cout << "--------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number of days: ";
    cin >> days;

    cout << "Enter a number of hours: ";
    cin >> hours;

    cout << "Enter a number of minutes: ";
    cin >> minutes;

    seconds = (days*86400)+(hours*3600)+(minutes*60);

    weeks = seconds/604800;

    cout << "--------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Equal to " << seconds  << " seconds" << endl;
    cout << "Equal to " << weeks << " weeks" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure there is something I'm doing wrong in the conversion part. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `seconds = (days/86400)+ ..` ... there are lots of seconds in a day. Possibly you meant `seconds = (days*86400)+..` (et cetera).

Comment: For the weeks calculation, you might want to add them in *minutes* and only then divide by minutes-per-week. This to prevent premature rounding.

Comment: How do you mean? I changed it to something like this, but weeks still returns as a garbage value. `seconds = (days*86400)+(hours*3600)+(minutes*60); weeks = seconds/604800 ;`

Comment: Once the solution has been found, accept an answer. If nobody posted a correct answer, write one yourself and accept it. (although you may not have sufficient karma to do that yet, someone will come along soon and convert Jongware's comment to an answer and then you can accept that). Please don't edit the original question to remove substantial details.

Answer (score 2):

All of your variables are `ints`, but you are performing very large divisions on them.  When an `int` is divided into a non-whole number, the decimal is dropped rather than rounded (so 3/2 = 1, for example).  The simplest way to fix this is to turn all your variables into `doubles` and possibly round them to two digits of precision using [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) on `cout`.  Alternatively, look into [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)

Answer (score 0):

Weeks is `int` and also all the elements of your division, this implies in an integer division. To get the proper result, you should make `weeks` `float` and convert one of the operands BEFORE the division, like:

```
float weeks = float(seconds) / 604800;
```

or

```
float weeks = seconds / 604800.0;
```

I strongly disencourage the second way because makes code more difficult to read.